# Lifetime of items in a Javascript Map() object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension (page action) with a `background.js` script.

In the `background.js` script, I define a `Map` object, that is cleared only in the `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` listener, which also adds an item to the `Map` object and immediately after opens a window:

```
var docsInBatch = new Map();

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  docsInBatch.clear();
  docsInBatch.set(doc.docid, { docid: doc.docid, fn: fileName, done: false });
  window.open(THE_URL);
```

then I wait for the THE_URL url to be loaded with a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info) {
  if (info.status == 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(newTab) {
      if ((newTab.url.lastIndexOf(THE_URL, 0) === 0) {
        alert('docsInBatch.size=' + docsInBatch.size);
      }
    });
```

Here, if the document to load at `THE_URL` takes a very long time to load (to the point that Chrome may even ask you if you wish to wait or cancel), I get `docsInBatch.size == 0`, which should not be because it must have at least one element, the one added on `chrome.pageAction.onClicked`.

It is just like someone cleared the objects in the Maps() object (perhaps the garbage collector?).

Why am I getting this behaviour only for long running processes? If it is the garbage collector clearing up items in a Map not used for a while, is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Do you have persistent: false in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have persistent:false in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `persistent: false` in the background manifest section. "When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources."

You can fix this by simply setting `persistent: true` or by saving the map to chrome.storage.local.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `Map` object is being cleared, but you can always store the object in `window.localStorage`. First you have to create functions to convert the `Map` to and from a string:

```
function mapToJson(map) {
    return JSON.stringify([...map]);
}
function jsonToMap(jsonStr) {
    return new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
}
```

Source: http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html

Then store your map in local storage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("myMap", mapToJson(map));
```

To retrieve the `Map`:

```
var map = jsonToMap(window.localStorage.getItem("myMap"));
```